# Degeneracy in Maxwell Boltzmann distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

While deriving Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution function we consider particles having degeneracy. But in classical mechanics how the concept of degeneracy of particle comes within?

Comment: i dont find this kind of information in any kind of books..

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437589/degeneracy-of-maxwell-boltzmann-distribution

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently quantum about the concept of degeneracy: it just means that different states can have the same energy.